# How to integrate tabs inside a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I would like to use the component tabs Android but within a layout. In fact, I would like the tabs is not sticking to my action bar in order to display information between.

Here is an example image of what I would get:

[image: Capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add tabs inside a [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

Here is a tutorial implementing this

http://www.betteropts.com/fragmenttabhost-tutorial-using-fragment-as-tab-content-and-keep-navigation-history-for-each-tab/

Comment: Nice thx. Does the FragmentTabHost for doing that : http://oi44.tinypic.com/ehkbk8.jpg